# Multiple search items from json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I've build an search filter to search in my items, but i've not one but 5 filters. But when i filter date everything is fine, but when i filter name and date i get only result on date and not on name and date.

```
    $( "input[name='name']" ).on("change paste keyup", function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value.length > 0) {
        getEventsByName('name',$(this).val());          
    }else{
        $("#block-a-events").empty();
        getEvents();
    }


});

$( "input[name='date']" ).on("change paste keyup", function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    var newDate = myDateFormatter(value);

    if(value.length > 0) {
        getEventsByName('date',newDate);            
    }else{
        $("#block-a-events").empty();
        getEvents();
    }


});

$( "#city" ).on("change", function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value.length > 0) {
        getEventsByName('location',value);          
    }else{
        $("#block-a-events").empty();
        getEvents();
    }


});

$( "#age" ).on("change", function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value.length > 0) {
        getEventsByName('age',value);           
    }else{
        $("#block-a-events").empty();
        getEvents();
    }


});

$( "input[name='genre']" ).on("change paste keyup", function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value.length > 0) {
        getEventsByName('genres',value);            
    }else{
        $("#block-a-events").empty();
        getEvents();
    }


});
```

Above you have the filter options and below you see how i filter in my object

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
var objects = [];
for (var i in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
        objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
    } else if (i.includes(key) && obj[key].includes(val)) {
        objects.push(obj);
    }
}
return objects;
}
```

Thats the handling, below you see what it does if everything is fine.

```
    function getEventsByName(key, value)
{
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '{url}',
        success : function(data)
        {
            var events = JSON.stringify(data);
            var filter = getObjects(data, key, value);

            $("#block-a-events").empty();

            $.each($.uniqueSort(filter), function(i, item) {

                content += '{html}';
                $("#block-a-events").append(content);

            })
        }
    })      
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every event you pass one  key => val pair to you filter function, and you filter des not hold any state. So each time it filters only one the key => val pair.

Best is to serialise all inputs and send them all via GET or POST request to the server (backend). Then filter everything there (in the backend). And show filtered json using js.

But is there is no backend filter, in order to filter by more than one input in frontend you can use several options. For example:

1. save the filer sate in an object. For example

   ```
   document.SomeGlobalDataPersistentObject = {};

   function getEventsByName(key, value)
    {
    document.SomeGlobalDataPersistentObject[key] = val;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '{url}',
        success : function(data)
        {
            var events = JSON.stringify(data);
            var filter = getObjects(data);
     ...
   }
   })
   }



    function getObjects(obj) { 
    var objects = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
    var tmpObjects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!objects.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        tmpObjects = [];
        for (key in document.SomeGlobalDataPersistentObject) {
            var val = document.SomeGlobalDataPersistentObject[key];
            if (typeof objects[i] === 'object') {
                tmpObjects = tmpObjects.concat(getObjects(tmpObjects[i]);
            } else if (i.includes(key) && objects[key].includes(val)) {
                tmpObjects.push(objects);
            }
        }
        objects = jQuery.extend(true, {}, tmpObjects);
        tmpObjects = []
    }
    return objects;
    }
   ```

   2. Or you better serialize all your form inputs not in the event listener function, but  some where in your the getObjects method:

      ```
      $( "input[name='name']" ).on("change paste keyup", function() {

      if(value.length > 0) {
          getEventsByName('name',$(this).val());          
      }else{
          $("#block-a-events").empty();
          getEvents();
      }

      });


       function getEvents()
       {
       $.ajax({
           dataType: 'json',
           url: '{url}',
           success : function(data)
           {
               var events = JSON.stringify(data);
               var filter = getObjects(data);
            ...
          }
      })
      }



      function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
      var objects = [];

      var filter = {
          'name':$( "input[name='name']" ).val(),
          'date':$( "input[name='date']" ).val(),
          'city':$( "#city" ).val(),
          'age':$( "#age" ).val()
      }

      for (var i in obj) {
          if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
          for (var key in filter) {
             ...
          }
      }
      return objects;
      }
      ```

P.S. sorry for code formatting

Answer (score 2):

assuming that your data is a valid json, maybe [JMESPATH](http://jmespath.org/) will help you filtering your data correctly.

It is a json query language.

For example: You can filter the following JSON by age > 20 with:

```
people[?age > `20`].{name: name, age: age}

{
  "people": [
    {
      "age": 20,
      "other": "foo",
      "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
      "age": 25,
      "other": "bar",
      "name": "Fred"
    },
    {
      "age": 30,
      "other": "baz",
      "name": "George"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result will look like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Fred",
    "age": 25
  },
  {
    "name": "George",
    "age": 30
  }
]
```

You can very easy use jmes by including the [jmespath.js](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.js) to your HTML via a script tag and then applying the filter:

```
let searchResult = jmespath.search([JSON], [your filter]);
```

Just see [the examples](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) for more information. There are also filters by date explained.

Comment: Thanks, but filtering works fine. but i can only filter one option not two option and that is why i ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you simply provide a text box that takes a search term. On the server you then check to see what filter it is and them search for an send back the relevant data using a query.

So for example i have a text box that says search. I enter a name or a city or place or thing into it. It then posts back to the server, there is for example a linq query that sees if there is a match for this entity that matches the search term.
For example does the customers entity have a record that matches the name or the city or the place or the thing, if so then send it.